Why is "Cauchy's criterion without an absolute value" not the standard form of Cauchy's criterion?
Cauchy's criterion (for sequences) says that a sequence $(a_n)$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all natural numbers $m,n>N$ we have $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$.
However, "Cauchy's criterion without an absolute value" is also true. Namely, a sequence $(a_n)$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all natural numbers $m,n>N$ we have $a_m-a_n<\epsilon$. The "only if" part is true from Cauchy's criterion and the fact that $x\leq |x|$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  The "if" part is true from Cauchy's criterion and the fact that $|a_m-a_n|\in\{a_m-a_n,a_n-a_m\}$.
"Cauchy's criterion without an absolute value" makes things easier in many cases, because often when one proves that a sequence is Cauchy, one needs to use the triangle inequality.
Why then is "Cauchy's criterion without an absolute value" not the standard form of Cauchy's criterion?

because we want to be able to talk about Cauchy’s criterion in spaces other than $\Bbb{R}$.

The meaning of $|a_m-a_n|$ is the distance between the elements. It is less intuitive what does $a_m-a_n$ represent. In the definition of a limit we also usually prefer $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ over $L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon$, even though they are equivalent. Also, in theoretical proofs, most of the time working with absolute value is actually easier. It makes us not worry about whether we work with positive or negative numbers. Splitting into cases every time wouldn't be fun.

@peek-a-boo ... Yes.  in particular, we want to allow complex numbers.

To extend peek-a-boo's point a little farther, a metric space $E$ is a set (of anything) along with a function $d : E \times E \to \Bbb R$, the metric, such that $d(x,x) = 0,  d(x, y) = d(y, x) > 0, d(x,y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x,z)$ for all $x, y, z \in E$. Sequences in $E$ are Cauchy if they satisfy the same condition with $|a_m - a_n|$ switched out for $d(a_m, a_n)$. $d(x,y) = |x - y|$ is a metric on $\Bbb R$, while $x - y$ is not. Most analysis occurs on metric spaces other than $\Bbb R$, Your change would make $\Bbb R$ a special case with special proofs, instead of just another application.
